# How to update record with the closest date from SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update one column for training in records where date is nearly actual date, and this select works fine:

```
SELECT MIN(training_id) AS training_id, date FROM training_terms WHERE 
date > CURRENT_DATE GROUP BY training_id
```

It pulls out the closest dates for each training, and I want to update column "visibility" in this select, so I tried write statement like this:

```
UPDATE training_terms SET visible='1' IN (SELECT MIN(training_id) 
AS training_id, date FROM training_terms WHERE date > CURRENT_DATE GROUP BY training_id);
```

but then that error appears in console (Linux):

```
You can't specify target table 'training_terms' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server here? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Why do you use `Min(training_id)? It is not necessary, because of `GROUP BY`, you don't aggregate rows...

Answer (score 1):

Use a `FROM` in a `UPDATE` is wrong.

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE training_terms
SET visible='1'
WHERE training_id IN
(SELECT training_id FROM (SELECT training_id, MIN(Abs(date - CURRENT_DATE))
FROM training_terms
WHERE date > Getdate()
GROUP BY training_id) AS t);
```

We use a subrequest to, for each ID, select the one that have a mininum difference between the date and today (so the closest)
And we use `Abs()` to make sure we select the closest in all case (future or past date)

Comment: Thank you, it is good but I have to distinct duplicates also, for example if I got training_id 123 and two terms are actual (04-20 and 05-20) then this statement (yours) will update two terms, and I need in order to it will update just one date, the closest one

Comment: So use a subrequest:

     UPDATE training_terms SET visible='1' 
        WHERE training_id
        IN (SELECT training_id, MIN(Day(date) - Day(CURRENT_DATE))
        FROM training_terms WHERE date > Getdate() GROUP BY training_id); (I edit my post)

Comment: I'm using MySQL so I tried your edited update statement with NOW() instead of Getdate(), but still doesn't works 'Operand should containt 1 column(s)' :(

Comment: Yes, I mistaked it again! Sorry ... When you use `WHERE something IN (sub_request)`, the subrequest should only have one column... But we have to select also MIN... So I suggest to surround subrequest with other one. I edit my post again

Comment: and @dante do you want to select only future dates? If it is not the case, juste remove `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

Below Script works in sql server . I change Current_Date to Getdate()

```
 UPDATE training_terms
    SET visible='1' 
    FROM training_terms
    WHERE training_id
    IN (SELECT MIN(training_id) 
    AS training_id FROM training_terms WHERE date > Getdate() GROUP BY training_id);
```

Comment: Do we really need to use a subrequest? I think only use the `WHERE` clause of `SELECT`...

Comment: but op needs minimum id

Comment: Also, I don't think  `Min(training_id)` is useful, because of the `GROUP BY`... Rows aren't aggregated ...

Comment: @Vinect, I want to distinct duplicates by this, if i write this without min(training_id) than it will pull out two dates for one training_id, I checked it already

Comment: You have duplicate IDs? Strange... But in this case you may only need `GROUP  BY`, but no MIN (sorry for edit, I misunderstood the question...)

Comment: And in the case of `UPDATE`, I think you want to update all duplicates, so if you aggregates rows, when you have many duplicates it will update randomly one of them...